# webapp2 Route to match all other paths

Tags: routes, webapp2

I've the following code in my main app. I expect all paths other than the first two to be caught by the last route (/.*). But I get 404 error. What am I missing?

```
  import webapp2
  from webapp2 import WSGIApplication, Route

  # ---- main handler
  class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      ret = jinja2render.DoRender(self)
      return ret

  routes = [
    Route (r'/rpc', handler = 'rpc.RPCHandler'),
    Route (r'/secured/somesecuredpage', handler = 'secured.securedPageHandler'),
    Route (r'/.*', handler = MainPage),
  ]

  app = WSGIApplication(routes, debug=True)
```

I can change the last route from "/.*" to "/<:.*>" to catch all other paths, but that also requires me to include a named parameter to MainPage.get function. Is that the only way to do or am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [URI template docs](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#the-url-template), this should do the trick:

```
Route (r'/<:.*>', handler=MainPage)
```

You may need to define your `MainPage.get` method as follows to accept with the extra arguments:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Yes, it appears that's the only way - add additional parameter(s) to get. Such as def get(self, param1) or def get(self, *arg, **kwargs).