# webapp.WSGIApplication to match all other possible paths

Tags: google-app-engine

I had gone through [webapp2 Route to match all other paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893528/webapp2-route-to-match-all-other-paths)

I try to

```
class SinkHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response.out.write('Sink')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    
    (r'/<:.*>', SinkHandler)
], debug = True)
```

in order to match

```
http://localhost:9080/dummy
http://localhost:9080/dummy/eummy
http://localhost:9080/dummy/eummy/fummy
```

But it just yield 404 not found.

I can do it this way.

```
class SinkHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response.out.write('Sink')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    
    (r'/(\w*)$', SinkHandler),
    (r'/(\w*)/(\w*)$', SinkHandler),
    (r'/(\w*)/(\w*)/(\w*)$', SinkHandler)
], debug = True)
```

It will able to match the above 3 type of URLs. However, if I need to support

```
http://localhost:9080/dummy/eummy/fummy/gummy
```

I need to add additional entry in `WSGIApplication`

Is there a smarter way, to match all other possible paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    
    (r'/.*', SinkHandler)
], debug = True)
```

To use the more general regexp, you need to use `Route`:

```
from webapp2 import Route

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    
    Route(r'/<:.*>', SinkHandler)
], debug = True)
```